# It is possible to change BEP-20 smart contract code?

Tags: smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain, bep20

I have deployed a contract on the BEP-20 network and now I don't need mint and owner address transfer functionality.
So I want to remove these options from the "write contract" options list.
If it is possible if yes then what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Smart contract bytecode is immutable. Assuming that your contract is not a [proxy](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/proxy) but a regular contract - you cannot change the already deployed code.

After you've made the changes in your local code, you'll need to recompile it, and deploy to a new address.